# The same password is not working across all Stack Exchange sites

Tags: support, login, password

I am not sure what happened in the last two days. Every time I log in to Stack Overflow I'm asked to reset my password.

I've been resetting my password in Stack Overflow for the last few days and the same password does not work across all Stack Exchange sites. Is it just for me or for others too?

Note:
I signed into Meta.stackexchange with my email and password. However, the same email and password doesn't work in Stack Overflow. I've reset the password in Stack Overflow. Once I log in to Stack Overflow, my Meta login doesn't work anymore.

Comment: How do you sign in? There are several options: Google, Facebook, GitHub, regular password... etc.

Comment: @Laurel, I sign in using my email and password.

Comment: This is happening even now. I signed into Meta.stackexchange with my email and password. However, the same email and password does not work in stackoverflow. I've to reset the password in stackoverflow. Once I login to stackoverflow, my Meta login doesn't work any more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was resolved using Gmail sign in instead of using email and password. I'm not really sure why email and password stopped working for the last two days.

Answer (score 12):

You have two emails attached to your account. One has a password and the other does not. Attempting to reset your password for the email which is not set up with a password actually redirects the request and resets the password for the other email which *is* set up with one. This can give the impression that the reset isn't working if you continue trying to login with the wrong email, because you need to be typing in a different email with that password.

If you want to use the other email with a password, you need to make sure it's set up with one. You can do so by heading to [My logins](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/mylogins/current) and adding a new credential, using the desired email and password to trigger a new verification email for it.

Comment: Thanks. Resolved by using google sign in. It works now.